# Two png's being displayed different in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, png

I've a weird problem that only occurs in Safari 6 on some mac's even with the same version of Safari and OSX.

The problem is three png's being displayed as a button, they're all css background-images and they've been exported by Photoshop's save for web feature from the same file at the same time with the same settings. But still Safari finds it neccesary to display a weird solid color on top of my png. The problem sometimes (partially) disappears when zooming in in the browser. Chrome, Firefox, IE on PC and Chrome and Firefox on Mac display the image normally. Below is a screenshot of the png.

[image: The left side of the button is displayed weird]

Has anybody seen this problem before? Is it just a bug in Safari or is there some sort of explaination? I can understand if there is a problem with gamma correction or color profiles, but that should not affect two similar image files, or at least affect them the same way so you cannot spot the difference.

I've created a Fiddle where you guys can see the code and the error aswell (if your mac is displaying it weird at least) [Click here for the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92TKT/18) But this is pretty much the css

```
.backbutton {
float: left;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.left {
display: block;
float: left;
background: url(http://daanolislagers.nl/btn-arrow-left.png) no-repeat 0 0px;
width: 17px;
height: 30px;
}

.middle {
display: block;
float: left;
background: url(http://daanolislagers.nl/btn-middle.png) repeat-x;
height: 23px;
font-size: 14px;
padding-top: 9px;
padding-left: 3px;
padding-right: 4px;
font-weight: normal;
color: inherit;
min-width: 190px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.middle {
min-width: 47px;
}

.right {
display: block;
float: left;
background: url(http://www.daanolislagers.nl/btn-right.png) no-repeat;
width: 3px;
height: 30px;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle so we can check it on MAC SAFARI too ?

Comment: Is there some color correction in effect on the computer? Color correction settings can be very confusing; e.g. the system corrects the color, but the application (Safari) can also correct the color, resulting in a overcorrection. And there seem to be settings that color correction should only be applied to images, not solid colors. Or only to some kinds of images (e.g. JPEGs but not GIFs). And images seem to be able to contain color correction tables of their own, which the computer can choose to ignore or not...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/92TKT/18/ it still does it in this fiddle, on two out of the three mac's we have.